# Can I use NSURLCredentialStorage with Data Protection?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, keychain

As far as I know, `NSURLCredentialStorage` is just a wrapper for the keychain services with a more convenient API. Which is why I'd like to use it. But I also want to take advantage of the Data Protection feature `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly` that keychain offers.

Is there a way to set this attribute when using NSURLCredentialStorage to store credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is Yes, kind of. I looked into the keychain item that `NSURLCredentialStorage` created. It is of the class `kSecClassInternetPassword` and has the access key `kSecAttrAccessible` set to "ak", which is `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`. So the password is not decrypted while the device is locked.

The only downside is that `NSURLCredentialStorage` doesn't offer a way to change that to `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly` to get an additional level of security for your backed-up data. You could only change that attribute manually on the keychain item using the lower level keychain APIs (i.e. `SecItemUpdate`).